# basic matrix determinant properties seem inconsistent

Tags: matrices, determinant

In my maths lecture notes it gives me these rules for the determinant of a matrix:

-If two rows or columns of a matrix are interchanged, the determintant is   multiplied by -1

-If a multiple of one row/column is added to another row/column, the determinant is unchanged

-If a row/column is multiplied by a real number a, the determinant is also multiplied by a

Unless theres something ive misunderstood, it seems that the second rule is inconsistent with the other two! i can swap two rows just using scale and add;

R1 <- R1 + R2

R2 <- R1 + (-1)*R2

R1 <- R1 + (-1)*R2

rule 2 says this should not affect the determinant. rule 1  says the determinant should be multiplied by -1! obviously i have missed something. Can anyone help?

Comment: You multiplied R2 by -1 in your second step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"If a multiple of one row/column is added to another row/column, the determinant is unchanged"

means $$R_j \leftarrow R_j +cRi$$

It does not include the case when

$$R_j \leftarrow R_i + cR_j$$

Comment: THIS is the piece of information i was missing. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In your three steps, you are multiplying the row by $-1$ in each step, so your determinant changes by $(-1)^3=-1$.